# Merging two pandas dataframe that are exactly the same without repeating columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that are exactly the same:

df1:

```
P1    ID
1     10
2     10
3     10
2     5
3     5
```

df2:

```
P2    ID
1     10
2     10
3     10
2     5
3     5
```

I want to merge them on ID, but I do not want to repeat the values of the P columns in the same row. That is I want the following result:

```
P1    ID    P2
1     10    2
1     10    3
2     10    1
2     10    3
3     10    1
3     10    2 
2     5     3
3     5     2
```

Is there a way to do this without doing regular merge and then removing rows with repeated values in P1 and P2?

Comment: But why `without doing regular merge and then removing rows with repeated values`

Comment: @yatu because the files are so large and I keep running out of memory. I can divide one of the dataframes into subframes and merge each separately and remove repeated values, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way

Comment: So you want no duplicates of `ID`, `P1`, or `P2`?

Comment: I'm sorry but the logic for merging is not clear here. Can you explain why/how the result is like this?

Comment: It looks to me like you want a cross join for each ID, but without rows where P1 == P2. I can't see it any other way, and your explanation leaves a lot to be desired. Help us out please?

Comment: A solution to what I _think_ your question is asking would be `df1.merge(df2, on='ID').query('P1 != P2')`

Comment: @Jaba I do not want to have a row where P1 and P2 have equal values.

Comment: What a beautiful dup target you've created @coldspeed :P.

Comment: @d_kennetz Thanks! I'd rather answer in the comments and close these basic merge questions as duplicate than leave them open to receive the same, tired answers over and over.